# display tree from reading csv file

Tags: python

hi i use this code its work for me with jupyter but i i would like to display tree for my own data  germen_credit.csv and not irish  what is the changes i try to read_csv but something is missing

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import pandas as pd
iris=datasets.load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y=iris.target

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(df,y)
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: how are you reading your csv?

Comment: Where is your csv file? with `pd.read_csv` you can read a csv and convert it to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

`df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)`

change it to `df=pd.read_csv('D://your_path_to_file//germen_credit.csv')`